# Random Choose set of data

Tags: python, random

I have three sets of data:

```
item1 = 'carrot'
property1 = 'vegetable'

item2 = 'apple'
property2 = 'fruit'

item3 = 'steak'
property3 = 'meat'
```

And so on... Now I want to combine these to sets of data, that should be randomly chosen.

```
combination1 = item1 + property1
combination2 = item2 + property2
combination3 = item3 + property3
```

So that I can use them randomly:

```
random.choice(combination1, combination2, combination3)
```

In the end the combination has to fit in here:

```
Client(args.item, args.property)
```

Problem is, that always the set of item1+property1,  item2+property2, aso. has to be taken. I can only manage to pick random combinations of items and properties, but don't know how to combine sets of them.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide your desired output as well?

Comment: But if the item and property are always linked, just don't select both of them at random! As soon as you pick one you already know what the other is.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you're asking. I see 2 different possible answers, and you're nearly answering one of them.

Comment: I need the random pairs. So IMCoins answered it. Couldn't describe it better. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random

#   Instead of doing this...
item1 = 'carrot'
property1 = 'vegetable'

item2 = 'apple'
property2 = 'fruit'

item3 = 'steak'
property3 = 'meat'

#   You might want to do this, so you can do more general work on your data.
items = ['carrot', 'apple', 'steak']
properties = ['vegetable', 'fruit', 'meat']

#   Now if you want to choose one item from both list at random, you can do...
for _ in range(5):
    random_choice = (random.choice(items), random.choice(properties))
    print 'This is a random set of item and property : {}'.format(random_choice)

#   If you want to choose a random pair of pre-computed items, you could...
#   1.  Group your data.
combs = [(item, property) for item, property in zip(items, properties)]

#   2. Choose at random your combined data.
for _ in range(5):
    random_pair = random.choice(combs)
    print 'This is the random selected pair : {}'.format(random_pair)
```

Outputs :

```
# This is a random set of item and property : ('apple', 'fruit')
# This is a random set of item and property : ('apple', 'meat')
# This is a random set of item and property : ('steak', 'vegetable')
# This is a random set of item and property : ('apple', 'vegetable')
# This is a random set of item and property : ('apple', 'vegetable')
# This is the random selected pair : ('steak', 'meat')
# This is the random selected pair : ('steak', 'meat')
# This is the random selected pair : ('steak', 'meat')
# This is the random selected pair : ('apple', 'fruit')
# This is the random selected pair : ('apple', 'fruit')
```

Comment: I need the random pairs. So this is it. Thank you! I'm just asking myself how the pairs are combined in this scenario. Is it the order in the set?

Answer (score 2):

You could define a class to hold your objects data and have a list of class objects like this. This way you could easily add extra fields to your object

```
import random

class Food:

    def __init__(self, name, type):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type

foods = [Food('carrot', 'vegetable'), Food('apple', 'fruit'), Food('steak', 'meat')]

random_food = random.choice(foods)
print(random_food.name)
print(random_food.type)
```

Comment: I like this way, too!